# Android: onActivityResult() is not calling

Tags: android, android-intent, tabactivity, activitygroup

I'm facing with a problem related  onActivityResult().

I use TabActivity as a main Activity. Each of the tabs is activityGroup.

A ActivityGroup's sub-activity A(Activity) sends the intent to B(Activity) using

startActivityForResult(   ,   ) .

But when B Activity finish, onActivityResult() is not called in A.

A Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

B Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

What is wrong?

Because of TabActivity, ActivityGroup or Flag??

Please advice..

Comment: I thought TabActivity was deprecated.

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated use FragmentActivity and onResultActivity is not calling due to ActivityGroup. See my Answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ActivityGroup inside TabActivity. I suppose finishFromChild will be invoked in parent activity (in TabHost). Check it.

Actually ... Do u really need ActivityGroup inside TabActivity?! Avoid it, e.g. use simple TabHost view in every tab of your parent TabActivity, this way TabActivity will switch views, not activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the `startActivityForResult` using the context of the `tabgroup activity` containing your current activity and then listen in the `tabgroup activity.`

Use this to get the `tabGroupActivity`:

```
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
```

And then call `startActivityForResult` from it:

```
parentActivity.startActivityForResult(...);
```

Finally , put an `onActivityResult` listener in the tabGroupActivity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code I hope it will work.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), B.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```